# slick 2.0, how to make the TableQuery map into a seq and finally map to form?

Tags: forms, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-2.0

I am new user of playframework 2.0.
I want to map the user object into a Form

I understand in slick 1.0 there is:

```
val userForm = Form(
 mapping(
"name" -> text,
"age" -> number
)(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply)
)
```

but in slick 2.0 the user is object:

```
class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String,String, String,Date,String,Option[Long], Int)](tag, "User") {
def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
def first_name = column[String]("First_Name")
def second_name=column[String]("Second_Name")
def email=column[String]("Email")
def datebirth=column[Date]("Birth_date")
def password=column[String]("Password")
def addID = column[Option[Long]]("ADRESS", O.Nullable)
def privilege=column[Int]("privilege")
def * = (id, first_name, second_name, email, datebirth, password, addID, privilege)
def home_address=foreignKey("ha_FK", addID, address)(_.id)
}
val user=TableQuery[User]
```

How object change to seq and then map to Form?

how the Form binds the data in scala2.0?

can anyone supply any example for this?

Answer (score 0):

The way it's often done is to use a case class to represent the object you want inserted in the database. Then you can easily create form mappings for your case class.

An example would be something like thais.

```
case class User(id: Option[Int] = None, name: String, age: Int)

class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User]("user") {
    def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("Name")
    def age = column[Int]("Age")
}

val users = TableQuery[UserTable]

val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "id" -> ignored
        "name" -> text,
        "age" -> number
    )
)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "change to Seq and then map to Form" but hopefully this is the answer you were looking for.